# Не могу собрать проект с build.gradle на Android Studio

Tags: java

Добрый день, возникла такая проблема не могу собрать проект `openVPN` на `Android Studio`.

Проект брал отсюда: `https://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/`

При сборке выдаёт следующие ошибки

```
error: package org.jetbrains.annotations does not exist
error: package org.jetbrains.annotations does not exist
```

Тут кидаю пример `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'

    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как включить те 2  библиотеки

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
```

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Тут проблема состоит в том, что есть два идентификатора группы, `org.jetbrains` и `com.intellij`. Именно в Maven Central лежит первый из них. Соответственно, нужно добавить строчку `compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0'` в depencencies.

Ещё одно важное замечание. Насколько я понимаю, это проект Android, поэтому нужно редактировать не файл, который лежит в корне, а файл в папке main.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте

```
compile 'com.intellij:annotations:12.0'
```

в секцию `dependencies`.

Comment: dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
        compile 'com.intellij:annotations:12.0'

}

Вот так прописал выдаёт ошибку при сборке

Gradle 'ics-openvpn-de5ded8017a3' project refresh failed:
         No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [com.intellij:annotations:12.0]
         Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)
         Build file 'C:\Users\onzone\AndroidStudioProjects\ics-openvpn-de5ded8017a3\build.gradle' line: 9

Comment: А если `compile 'com.intellij:annotations:+@jar'`?

Comment: Тоже пробовал на stackoverflow описано =) Но не помогло. Я думаю как можно пакет к проекту подрубить другим образом не через градл? У меня проблема только в эту либу упирается. То есть если закоментить всё что к ней относится, то проект собирает.

Comment: Ну так и удалите её. Это всего лишь аннотации для статического анализа. Или замените их на соответствующие из JSR 305.